# Unknown error while inserting data into sqlite database table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, logcat

This is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFHkE.png

I don't mean only the error on the selected line but what's going on when I click the button.

The LoginOpenHelper's getIDUsuario method code is the following:

```
public String getIDUsuario(String usuario, String senha){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String id = "id_usuario";

        String[] columns = {id};
        String[] selectionArgs ={usuario, senha};

        Cursor cursor = db.query("usuarios", columns, "nome_usuario=? AND senha=?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(id);
            int idUsuario = cursor.getInt(index0);
            buffer.append(idUsuario);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

Line 91 is this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("usuarios", columns, "nome_usuario=? AND senha=?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

This is the code for the cadastrarTransacao method in the MockActivityTransacao class:

```
public void cadastrarTransacao(View view) {
        TransacaoDTO transacaoDTO = new TransacaoDTO();
        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();

        //int idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(activity.getIDUsuario(loginOpenHelper));

        transacaoDTO.setDesc(edtDescricao.getText().toString());
        transacaoDTO.setData(edtData.getText().toString());
        transacaoDTO.setValor(Long.parseLong(edtValor.getText().toString()));
        transacaoDTO.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(loginOpenHelper.getIDUsuario(loginDTO.getUsuario(), loginDTO.getSenha())));

        ValidacaoMock resultado = mockBO.cadastrarOperacao(transacaoDTO);

        MensagemUtil.addMsg(this, resultado.getMensagem());

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MockListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Line 53 is this one:

```
transacaoDTO.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(loginOpenHelper.getIDUsuario(loginDTO.getUsuario(), loginDTO.getSenha())));
```

I think the problem is that the code is not retrieving the values from LoginDTO, which has this code:

```
public class LoginDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1111108194849414002L;

    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

I can't think about a way to solve it.

Comment: @MohammedAli it's on the link right here http://i.imgur.com/eR1N1j0.png

Comment: @MikeOliveira you should add the actual error information _in the question itself_, not (just) as a link.

Comment: see answer, check if any of selectionArgs is null.

Answer (score 0):

"The bind value" points to the selectionArgs of the query. If any one of the selectionArgs value is null, you can get this error. Print in logcat and check if

```
String[] selectionArgs ={usuario, senha};
```

any one usuario or senha is null.